# I have too many versions of Ruby and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have both ruby and rails installed in:
    /usr/local/bin/ruby
    /usr/bin/ruby
    /usr/local/bin/ruby

This is causing problems when I try to run certains commands like ruby script/console

How do I remove some of these installations of both ruby and rails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RVM will help you for sure.  Check out [RVM here](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)

Comment: I dont really need to have multiple versions - will RVM help with removing versions?

Comment: No, but in each of your projects directory, you will have a .rvm config telling which version of ruby and rails this project use.  So you won't have problems with older/newer version installed

Comment: Uninstall all ruby and rails versions from your system with your package manager. Then go get RVM - Ruby enVironment (Version) Manager (RVM). It's an awesome tool to manage your Ruby installations.

Comment: which version and where they are located?

Answer (score 8):

Preventing this kind of situations is the very role of [RVM](https://rvm.io) and it's gemsets.

I encourage you to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. First one would be to get your ruby system install in good order. There is no harm in renaming removing those multiple ruby file in your diverse bin folders. Get the stable release of 1.9.2 and gem install whatever you need then. Googling around to fill the gaps you may have [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-install-ruby-1-9-2-and-rails-3-0-on-ubuntu-10-10-4148.html)

Quick and dirty you can do:

Get the latest stable release of ruby 1.9.2, compile it on your system, I suppose the ruby that is under /usr/bin is the system's and you are using macosx. The one located in /usr/local/bin is probably something you installed yourself and even maybe you don't even need to reinstall ruby 1.9.2. If that's so get you .bashrc in proper order by making sure /usr/local/bin comes before /usr/bin and you won't have to worry so much about which version you might be using. Create a ~/.bash_profile and put this in.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Expected output (more or less):

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
```

Others mentioned RVM. I used it, but I don't use it on a production server, I prefer a single sane ruby install to RVM. There is also [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and is seems much saner.

Final thought play around in your system remove symlink stuff, set your PATH variable or use RVM/rbenv.

Answer (score -1):

Managing Ruby: Moving From RVM to rbenv

It's time to switch over, http://cantina.co/2011/10/08/managing-ruby-moving-from-rvm-to-rbenv/